# Java Applets - repaint

Tags: java, applet, repaint

I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class DrawExample extends Applet 
{
    Font bigFont;

     Color redColor;
     Color weirdColor;
     Color bgColor;

     public void init() 
     {
          bigFont = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,16);
          redColor = Color.red;
          weirdColor = new Color(60,60,122);
          bgColor = Color.yellow;
      setBackground(bgColor);
     }

     public void stop()
     {
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g) 
     {
      g.setFont(bigFont);
      g.drawString("TESTING",80,20);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.drawRect(100,100,100,100);
      g.fillRect(110,110,80,80);
      g.setColor(weirdColor);
      g.fillArc(120,120,60,60,0,360);
      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      g.drawLine(140,140,160,160);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
     }
}
```

I dont know how to "repaint" the output I get.. lets say I want the applet to start and after 3 seconds I want to repaint the "picture" so that background color changes to red (or whatever). How do I do that? How do I change the output ever 3 seconds?

Comment: BTW - Don't use AWT components in this day and age.  Those of who used it have largely forgotten the details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your title, try calling the [repaint() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29). You can use a [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to execute the `repaint()` method every 3 seconds/

Example:

```
boolean colourIsRed = false;
int delay = 1000; //1 second
int period = 3000; //3 seconds

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    if (colourIsRed) {
      setBackground(Color.blue);
      colourIsRed = false;
   }
   else {
      setBackground(Color.red);
      colourIsRed = true;
   }         

   repaint();
  }
}, delay, period);
```

Comment: `TimerTask` does not honor the single thread requirements of Swing, each tick of the timer is executed outside of the Event Dispatching Thread.  You should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`.  Besides, the OP's paint is bad

Comment: OP is using AWT, does the single thread requirement apply for this?

Comment: Good question, as I understand it AWT components are Thread safe :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer  My understanding differs from yours.  AFAIU, Oracle *should* always have been issuing the same warnings about AWT as it does with Swing.  I figure it was just 'Swing time' before they realized, and the helper methods were already in Swing, so they could not be bothered trying to backdate the info.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This always confuses the living day lights out of me. I simply treat all UI methods as non-thread safe personally